# combination of distinct in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get the combination of distinct value. That i have explained below

Example 1: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw3rg.png)

here i have highlighted in yelow colour has source system,party id and group number as duplicate. in this case if the combination of source system,party id and group number is duplicated then need to check the max of last update date and eliminate one record

example 2:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhvJi.png)

Here I have highlighted in yellow colour has source system, party id, group number, Last update date and creation date as duplicate. in this case if the combination of the source system, party id, group number,Last update date and creation is duplicated then need to get the combination of all the five-column as distinct

```
select 
"Source System",
"Group Number",
"Partner Party Id"
from 
VT_PC_DE_DUP_CONSOLIDATED_JAN_22_INC
where 
("Source System" in (select "Source System" from VT_PC_DE_DUP_CONSOLIDATED_JAN_22_INC group by "Source System","Group Number","Partner Party Id"
having count("Source System")
= 1)
and "Group Number" in (select "Group Number" from VT_PC_DE_DUP_CONSOLIDATED_JAN_22_INC group by "Source System",
"Group Number","Partner Party Id" having count("Group Number")
= 1)
and "Partner Party Id" in (select "Partner Party Id" from VT_PC_DE_DUP_CONSOLIDATED_JAN_22_INC group by "Source System",
"Group Number","Partner Party Id" having count("Partner Party Id")
= 1))
or "Partner Last Update Date Ref" in (select max("Partner Last Update Date Ref") from VT_PC_DE_DUP_CONSOLIDATED_JAN_22_INC group by
"Source System",
"Group Number","Partner Party Id","Partner Last Update Date Ref")
or "Partner Creation Date Ref" in (select max("Partner Creation Date Ref") from VT_PC_DE_DUP_CONSOLIDATED_JAN_22_INC group by
"Source System",
"Group Number","Partner Party Id","Partner Last Update Date Ref","Partner Creation Date Ref")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you correctly, you can just use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (source_system, party_id) vt.*
from vt_pc_de_dup_consolidated_jan_22_inc vt
order by source_system, party_id, last_update_date desc
```

This gives you the latest record per `(source_system, party_id)` tuple, based on `last_update_date`. If there are ties, only one is picked.